# What do I do when the NSZombie causing a crash is a class?

Tags: objective-c, nszombie

So I've just started using Instruments to try to debug my app more in depth as I have recently developed a zombie problem. All was going well up to the point of me realising that the category of the zombie is a class of mine called "CreaterPage".

All the examples I've seen of removing zombies had the category listed as something like a string. I therefore have no idea how to go about fixing this problem and removing the zombie

If anybody can offer any tips or answers they would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 2):

A zombie just means that you're trying to send messages to an object that has been deallocated. The class of the zombie object doesn't really matter (except in that it might help you pinpoint the root of the problem).

Instruments should give you some information about the zombie object, where it was allocated etc. It's up to you to figure why your code was trying to message a dead object. Often this will be because you forgot to retain an object, released something you didn't have ownership of or kept on using something after you released it.